# Lord of Happiness Venkateshwara, Godess Mahalakshmi devi and Lord of Wealth Kuberan

Tags: lakshmi, venkateshwara

I want to know why that Lord Venkateshwara swamy got the credit from Lord Kubera however Goddess Mahalakshmi is wife of MahaVishnu itself.